# Should I have identity column in every table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I know it may be appear that the question is duplicate, but I ask for my case. In my database, I have two tables one for user and the second for images of that user. My question is should I have identity column in the Images table ?

[image]

I know that the big question ( Should I have identity column in every table ? ) have many answers and most answers say ( it depend on your case ), so I want to know for may case what should I do ?

Comment: Does every image relate to a single user or can some images relate to multiple users?

Comment: Every image related to a single user.

Comment: Can a user have more than one image?

Comment: I wouldn't say you should have identity in every table, but you definitely should have unique key (single value or composite) that cannot be changed in every table.

Comment: Yes the use can have multiple images.

Comment: I could make (UserID and ImageSrc) as unique key, but I ask for the identity. @JamesZ

Comment: @AhmedShamel Yes you could, but I wouldn't recommend that. Using ImageSrc (that's the path?) in other tables as a foreign key sounds quite bad.

Comment: @JamesZ UserID is the foreign key to relate Images table to the UserInfo table. I mean that I could make (UserID and ImageSrc) as a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an identity column. Unless you have  table that connects to the images table (such as image details or something like that), or if you need to sort the user images by the time they where saved in the database, an identity column on your images table is going to be useless. Having your primary key as well as your clustered index on the userId + imageSrc will give you better searches. Note that you will need a unique ImageSrc anyway, otherwise you might overwrite images on the file system.

Comment: Good answer, but if I want to sort the images I think it is better to add a datetime column instead of identity column.

Comment: If it's only for sort you better use an identity column since it's storage space is smaller then a datetime column. If you actually need the date,  then use a date column.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, otherwise you wouldn't be able to select the user's corresponding image from the image table. (This is if you choose to go with 2 tables.)

However if a user will only ever have 1 image associated with them, you could just have an ImageSrc column in the user table containing the src of that single image

Comment: The user have many images.
I can write the query ( select ImageSrc from Images where UserID='somthing' ) and get all images for that user

Comment: Well in this case, your second table should be some additional information. Otherwise the ordering and everything else related to your imageSrc will be very random. In this case it may be better to have an ordering Column or an id itself for the image table, and an additional column userid, which helps to join those two tables.